# Como recorrer un array que en su interior tiene números enteros e identificar cual de ellos es un numero perfecto en java

Tags: java, array

Este es mi codigo tengo que decir que mi primera intencion era hacer una matriz que el tamaño lo
definiera el usuario ingresandolos e igual los numeros para llenar la matriz, entonces me dispoce a hacerlo mas sencillo porque al parecer solo me hace una vuelta el for no continua el ciclo hasta la condicion.

```
import  java.util.*;
public class Ejemplo_Array_D2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        
        
        int z =0;
        int suma=0;
        
        int [] saldo = {3,28,5,6};
        
        for(int i=0; i<saldo.length; i++) {
            
        }
        
        for( z=0; z<saldo.length; z++) {
            
                for(int x = 1; x<saldo[z]; x++) {
                
                    if(saldo[z] % x == 0) {
                
                        suma = suma + x;
                        
                    }   
                    
                }
                
                if(suma == saldo[z]) {
                    
                    System.out.print("Este es un numero perfecto "+saldo[z]);
                    
                }
                    
        }

        
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes de cuidar donde abres y cierras llaves en este caso debes iterar el array para tomar uno por uno los elementos y evaluarlos si cumplen con la condicion de ser perfectos

```
    int [] saldo = {3,28,5,6};
    
       for (int i=0;i<saldo.length;i++){//abre 1
           
           for (int z = 1; z < saldo[i]; z++) {  //abre2                          
                if (saldo[i] % z == 0) {
                    suma = suma + z;   
                }
            }//cierra 2
            if (suma == saldo[i]) {                     
                System.out.println(saldo[i]+" es Perfecto");
            } else {
                System.out.println(saldo[i]+" No es perfecto");
    
            }
 //luego de haber evaluado el primer elemento del array debes limpiar el valor
 //acumulado para que este no tome todos los elementos del array
         suma=0;
       } //cierra 1
```

Comment: Gracias amigo eres muy bueno en programacion, cuando veo este tipo de cosas me doy cuenta de que no es lo mio esto, pero esta genial que haya gente tan inteligentes como ustedes